# What is the difference between these two ways of saving keras machine learning model weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I saw two ways of saving the weights of a keras model.

First way;

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    nb_epoch=number_of_epoch,
                    batch_size=128,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr, checkpointer],
                    shuffle=True)
```

Second way;

```
model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

What is the difference between the two ways? Any difference in prediction performance between loading `weights.hdf5` and `model_weights.h5`?

Comment: You tell us -- did it have an impact?

Comment: @erip, I just discovered first method always save the best weights. No guarantee for the second method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, there is no difference performance-wise. These are just two different ways of how and especially when the model shall be saved. Using `model.save_weights` requires to especially call this function whenever you want to save the model, e.g. after the training or parts of the training are done. Using `ModelCheckpoint` is much more convenient if you are still developing a model. Using this way, `keras` can save a checkpoint of your model after each training epoch, so that you can restore the different models; or you can set `save_best_only=True` so that `keras`  will overwrite the latest checkpoint only if the performance has improved, so that you end with the best performing model.

To summarize it: these are just two different ways of doing two different things. It depends on your use case and needs, what's the best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Upvoted. I think there is a key difference. Using `ModelCheckpoint` with  `save_best_only=True`, one is guaranteed to save the best weights. No guarantee for the other method. So, `save_best_only=True` is always better. I cannot think of any other reason not to use it all the time.

Comment: @FlashTek, can you also tell us the difference between hdf5 and h5? Both are saving the model with weight, correct? Thanks

Comment: @FloridaMan It's the same. Just different file extensions, but otherwise the files will be identical. `*.h5` and `*.hdf5` are synonymous file extensions.

Answer (score 6):

### HDF5 (.h5, .hdf5)

As fundamentally explained here [reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html)

> `HDF` is an acronym for Hierarchical Data Format. `HDF5` is HDF
> Version 5.

```
Import["file.h5"]
```

> imports an HDF5 file, returning
> the names of the datasets stored in the file.

In Keras documents; as you can see here [keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/)

```
model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
```

In Tensorflow documents; as you can see here [tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)

```
# Save the entire model to a HDF5 file.
# The '.h5' extension indicates that the model should be saved to HDF5.
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

At fundamental level they are same thing. They cant create  any difference.