# Converted tfjs model throwing model config null errors

Tags: image, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use a converted Keras model (https://github.com/idealo/image-quality-assessment/tree/master/models/MobileNet) in tfjs. 
All of the Keras conversion examples mention h5 files, while these are hdf5 files. Is there a difference between them? 
When I tried using the converted model I get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'model_config' of null

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923048/what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-ways-of-saving-keras-machine-learning-mod) talking about  h5 and hdf5. how are you loading the model in your js code ? Can you show a bit of code ?

Comment: Here is how the model is loaded. This is the converted tfjs model                                  ```public async loadModel() {
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      'assets/mobilenet/model.json'
    )
  }```

Comment: Currently facing the same problem. Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Facing same problem. Any soln found yet???